# Unable to create a manifest resource name for and .cs file is missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc0jl.png)

I tried to check in and something is broken.

It is saying Unable to create a manifest resource name for "Search.resx". Could not find the "someaddress\search.cs"

I tried to change .csproj file .. but not working..
when I try to add exist item, there's no search.cs file..

so my solution is not working not at all.

Anyone knows how can I solve this problem?

Comment: From my experience this is a form program ? Have you tried restarting visual studio? Did you try to create a new application replication migration? Still having the same problem?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e531ee77-742d-402a-97ae-e6dd32c20b20/a-yellow-rectangle-appears-on-my-project-files?forum=tfsversioncontrol